# How to return http error responses with spring boot when using constraint annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I'm working on a project using React and Spring-boot. Up to this point, i have managed to make a sign up page that inserts users (username, password, email) to a postgres database managed from spring boot. However, now i want to filter this input in the backend side so i dont get unwanted usernames, passwords, emails.

After some google searching i found that i could do that using annotations constraints like @Pattern and @Size. Using annotations seems to currently satisfy my needs. Pleas feel free to suggest a better approach if there is one.

My question is how do i return a unique http error message to the react frontend. It seems to me that every annotation should have its own error id. For example,

```
@Column(name = "password")
@Pattern(regexp = "[^\s]*", message = "Password should not contain whitespaces")
@Size(min = 8, max = 16, message = "Password should be between 8 and 16 characters")
private String userPassword;
```

In order to inform the client at the frontend side, i somehow need to get an error id or message.

Sending some invalid input using postman i get 400 error messages but the JSON returned is too complicated. I dont need so much info, just the source error.

Strangely, using the unique true constrain

```
@Column(name = "email", unique = true)
private String userEmail;
```

gives me a 500 status error and also the json describing the error is all different from the 400 ones.

I simply want to return 40x errors with simple json structure describing the error. Ideally, i would like to handle exceptions either caused by the annotations or because i manually throw an exception inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

You need one of these:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionHandler {

  // this catches everything that you don't handle specifically.
  @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
  @ResponseStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  public ErrorMessage handleException(Exception e) {
    log.warn("An unexpected error occurred", e);
    return ErrorMessage
      .builder()
      .cause("Internal server error")
      .detail(e.getMessage())
      .build();
  }

  @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public ErrorMessage handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {

    log.info(e.getMessage());

    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = e.getConstraintViolations()
        .stream()
        .map(violation -> FieldError
            .builder()
            .description(violation.getMessage())
            .field(violation.getPropertyPath().toString())
            .rejectedValue(violation.getInvalidValue())
            .build())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ErrorMessage
        .builder()
        .cause("Constraint violation")
        .detail("The request was invalid.")
        .fieldErrors(fieldErrors)
        .build();
  }
}
```

You can add in other handlers as required (NOT_FOUND, CONFLICT etc.) and also more BAD_REQUEST handlers for other types of exception (MethodArgumentNotValidException, MissingServletRequestParameterException, HttpMessageNotReadableException).

Think long and hard about the structure of the errors you return as they form part of your API contract with your clients and once released into the wild, will require great care when changing them. Also, be careful using the exception message in your response as this may reveal details of your implementation - knowing that you've used Java and Spring Boot might give an attacker a foot in the door).

As for unique error codes, that's a whole other world of fun. I'd suggest keeping them simple and generic. Use mnemonics as opposed to codes that are not intuitive. e.g. MandatoryField is easier to understand than ABC-00234.